# Laravel Mix and importing files

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

I am using Laravel 7 and have quite a few javascript files in public/js which I currently cann in my app template such as

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/stt.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/ilightbox.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.requestAnimationFrame.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.mousewheel.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/sidenav.js') }}" defer></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/spectrum.js') }}" defer></script> 
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.printElement.js') }}" defer></script>
```

also I have a bunch of css such as

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('css/sidenav.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="{{ asset('jqueryui/jquery-ui.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="{{ asset('jqueryui/jquery-ui.structure.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="{{ asset('jqueryui/jquery-ui.theme.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="{{ asset('css/stt.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="{{ asset('css/general.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="{{ asset('css/ilightbox.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="{{ asset('css/flex.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('fontawesome/css/all.css')}}">
```

I am totally confused about to include these in a mix and the syntax to use in the webpack.mix.js file.

Following a comment I changed the mix file to:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css'),
.css(
    ['public/css/sidenav.css',
    'public/css/general.css',
    'resources/asset/jqueryui/jquery-ui.min.css',
    'resources/asset/jqueryui/jquery-ui.structure.min.css',
    'public/css/stt.css',
    'public/css/ilightbox.css',
    'public/css/flex.css',
    'public/css/general.css',
    'resources/asset/fontawesome/css/all.css',
    'public/css/smartforms/smart-forms.css',
    'public/css/smartforms/smart-themes/blue.css',
    'public/css/hover-min.css',
    'public/css/klik.css',
    'public/css/spectrum.css',
    'public/css/infobox.css',
    ],'resources/css/app.css','public/css'),

 .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
    require('tailwindcss')],
```

but when I ran it I got and error and the npm log file is

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Jim\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_module\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'dev'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.10
3 info using node@v14.15.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle @~predev: @
6 info lifecycle @~dev: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~dev: PATH: C:\Users\Jim\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Laravel\jsp\node_modules\.bin;C:\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Python39\;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;c:\php;c:\bat;C:\Program Files\Calibre2\;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\;C:\Users\Jim\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Jim\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\Jim\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Users\Jim\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Jim\.dotnet\tools
9 verbose lifecycle @~dev: CWD: C:\Laravel\jsp
10 silly lifecycle @~dev: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'npm run development' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~dev: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~dev: Failed to exec dev script
13 verbose stack Error: @ dev: `npm run development`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jim\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jim\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd C:\Laravel\jsp
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Jim\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "dev"
18 verbose node v14.15.3
19 verbose npm  v6.14.10
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @ dev: `npm run development`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46252325/how-to-compile-two-scss-file-into-one-css-file-in-laravel-with-laravel-mix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Javascript method chaining, there is no need to separate them with commas (,).

You probably got the following syntax error

```
webpack.mix.js:15
    .css([
    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

...

npm ERR! errno 1
```

And try a simple merge using styles() instead of css().

Try this.

```js
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .styles(
        [
            'public/css/sidenav.css',
            'public/css/general.css',
            'resources/asset/jqueryui/jquery-ui.min.css',
            'resources/asset/jqueryui/jquery-ui.structure.min.css',
            'public/css/stt.css',
            'public/css/ilightbox.css',
            'public/css/flex.css',
            'public/css/general.css',
            'resources/asset/fontawesome/css/all.css',
            'public/css/smartforms/smart-forms.css',
            'public/css/smartforms/smart-themes/blue.css',
            'public/css/hover-min.css',
            'public/css/klik.css',
            'public/css/spectrum.css',
            'public/css/infobox.css',
        ], 'public/css/app-combine.css')
//    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
//        require('tailwindcss')
//    ])
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('/css/app.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('/css/app-combine.css') }}">
```

> resources/sass/app.scss -> public/css/app.css

---

If successful without problems, i recommend that you differentiate between apps and vendors as follows.

```js
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .styles(
        [
            'resources/asset/jqueryui/jquery-ui.min.css',
            'resources/asset/jqueryui/jquery-ui.structure.min.css',
            'resources/asset/fontawesome/css/all.css',
        ], 'public/css/vendor-combine.css')
    .styles(
        [
            'public/css/sidenav.css',
            'public/css/general.css',
            'public/css/stt.css',
            'public/css/ilightbox.css',
            'public/css/flex.css',
            'public/css/general.css',
            'public/css/smartforms/smart-forms.css',
            'public/css/smartforms/smart-themes/blue.css',
            'public/css/hover-min.css',
            'public/css/klik.css',
            'public/css/spectrum.css',
            'public/css/infobox.css',
        ], 'public/css/app-combine.css')
//    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
//        require('tailwindcss')
//    ])
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('/css/vendor-combine.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('/css/app.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('/css/app-combine.css') }}">
```

Laravel mix doc - https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/concatenation-and-minification

Comment: Just one question. I tried to combine some js files but got an error I tried .js('/public/jqueryui/jquery-ui.js' 'public/js/stt.js) but I got a syntax error. What is the correct syntax to combine javascript files into one?

Comment: Ignore my last comment - sorted!